# Как перевести bytes в последовательность едениц и нолей python

Tags: python

Нужно преобразовать последовательность байтов в список из едениц и нолей
например:

```
b'hello' == [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0] # (примерно так, незнаю как будет)
```

Как лучше это сделать (можно любым способом, чтобы можно было дешифровать)?

Comment: Показанный вами пример намекает, что вы сами не понимаете чего хотите, ну а мы тем более не знаем

Comment: Возможно, Вы хотели перевести текст в двоичный код? Чтобы в конечном итоге было что-то типо: hello = [1001000 1100101 1101100 1101100 1101111]`. Конкретизируйте, пожалуйста.

Comment: Нет, мне нужно переводить впринципе байты а не текст

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Например:

```py
result = []
for b in b'hello':
    result.extend(map(int, f'{b:08b}'))
print(result)
```

Вывод:

```
[0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

Или тоже самое в список списков, тогда поменять строку добавления на:

```
    result.append(list(map(int, f'{b:08b}')))
```

Вывод:

```
[[0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1], [0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1]]
```

Есть и другие варианты.

Comment: А как можно расшифровать полученый результат?